# Share cocoapods with custom framework included in project

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

For the following Architecture:

_Code
___CustomFramework
___ProjectA
_____ProjectA
_____Workspace
_____Podfile
_____Pods

I am using workspace of ProjectA (generated by podfile), and I have included CustomFramework inside ProjectA successfully, I can use methods from CustomFramework inside ProjectA.

Now, I would like to share ProjectA's pods with CustomFramework. So I can use methods from ProjectA's pods inside CustomFramework. That's where i'm stuck and need help.

What I have tried so far:
But I am not sure if it is the right way, or the good syntax to link CustomFramework

> PODFILE
>   platform :ios, '8.0'
>
> link_with 'ProjectA', 'CustomFramework'
>
> pod 'nameofpod', '3.1.0'

I also have set **'Allow non-modular includes in Framework Modules'** and set it to **YES**, for both the Project file (blue) and the Custom Framework

But CustomFramework still doesn't recognize my pods :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to write the podfile in that way:

```
workspace 'AllInOne.xcworkspace'
xcodeproj 'ProjectA/ProjectA.xcodeproj'
xcodeproj 'CustomFramework/CustomFramework.xcodeproj'

target 'ProjectA' do
  platform :ios, '8.0'
  xcodeproj 'ProjectA/ProjectA.xcodeproj'
  pod 'nameofpod', '~> 3.1'
end

target 'CustomFramework' do
  platform :ios, '8.0'
  xcodeproj 'CustomFramework/CustomFramework.xcodeproj'
  pod 'nameofpod', '~> 3.1'
end
```

Comment: It does a good job on the architecture. I have imported <Restkit/..> (one of my pod) in my CustomFramework.h file, but it is still not found. But it is found in ProjectA.

Comment: Did you create the podfile in the folder where the ProjectA and the folder CustomFramework are?

Comment: The folder should have these files:

AllInOne/ProjectA/ProjectA.xcodeproj,

AllInOne/CustomFramework/CustomFramework.xcodeproj,

AllInOne/podfile,

AllInOne/AllInOne.xcworkspace

Comment: Yup that's exactly what I have, does it needs a specific setting in CustomFramework or ProjectA ? Everything else is working like a charm :-/

Comment: I ended up adding "pod 'nameofpod', '~> 3.1'" for each target, it add the pod once, but seems to configure it for each target. Is that the right way to go ? If you can update your answer I will accept it as the right answer. Thx. I also have read : https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/738

Comment: It should be ok..Do you get an error when you compile it? Or you cannot find libraries when you try to fill a name of a library in CustomFramework.
Because this is what it happens to me. When I try to fill a name of a library, the name doens't appear, but when I compile it, it finds the library.

Comment: From the moment, pod is adding once, I don't see why shouldn't be right.
I just updated my answer.

Comment: No error on compile, and all name and autocomplete found. I imported my framework into my project PCH file.

Comment: With this approach, I get complaints about either libraries or classes (if use_frameworks! is defined) being included twice (e.g. "Class Foo is implemented in both ProjectA and CustomFramework. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined."). Haven't found a way to avoid that. By the looks of it, in the example above 'nameofpod' would be included twice in the compiled project - once in ProjectA and again in CustomFramework. Is there some other change required to solve this problem?