# Using Cocoapods with custom framework that also needs third party libraries

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I've been running into a bit of a problem trying to find a set up that would work for my situation:

I'm building 2 iOS applications and a framework that's being shared between the 2 apps. Lets call the apps app A and app B.

So for both apps A and B I have cocoapods set up and the shared framework is being added as a submodule. I didnt want to create a pod for my framework cuz it's being developed at the same time(is it a good reason to not create a pod for it?).

So everything is fine till the framework needs its own third party dependencies, since I can't use cocoapods for the framework as it's being added as subproject into project A and B' workspaces, I had to do a "dirty" job of just embedding the framework's third party libraries into its project just to keep going.

But obviously this is not going to scale well, I was wondering if any of you guys have had similar situations and how did you go about managing it? I was thinking maybe using Carthage for the framework to keep track of the dependencies and for the project A and B still us Cocoapods.

Any pointers would be much appreciated, thanks

Let me know if you need any clarifications or if I'm missing something.

---

I've found something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/26168055/8529947

but the thing that I'm not sure about this approach is doing this will modify build settings of the shared framework which is not a good idea since both project A and B will be modifying the shared framework build settings at the same time. Is that the case or am I missing something here?

Comment: My thoughts only. (1) A framework should *normally not* use third party libraries. (2) If you *must* build a framework that uses a third party library, use *only* one  - *and* - treat (or code) with it like an extension. Otherwise you will end up with more "interdependencies" that you want. If not now, someday. Frameworks should **always** stand on their own. But sure, there are exceptions - just be sure to have an extremely good reason for that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I agree framework should normally not depend on third party libraries, the dependencies should be exposed through abstract interfaces. The framework in this case is not strictly a "framework" in a pure definition, it also contains common code between 2 projects.